# What is the difference between a static global and a static volatile variable?

Tags: c, static, global, interrupt, volatile

I have used a static global variable and a static volatile variable in file scope,

both are updated by an ISR and a main loop and main loop checks the value of the variable.

here during optimization neither the global variable nor the volatile variable are optimized. So instead of using a volatile variable a global variable solves the problem.

So is it good to use global variable instead of volatile?

Any specific reason to use static volatile??

Any example program would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are different things. I'm not an expert in volatile semantics. But i think it makes sense what is described here.

#### Global

Global just means the identifier in question is declared at file-scope. There are different scopes, called  function (where goto-labels are defined in), ﬁle (where globals reside), block (where normal local variables reside), and function prototype (where function parameters reside). This concept just exist to structure the visibility of identifiers. It doesn't have anything to do with optimizations.

#### Static

`static` is a storage duration (we won't look at that here) and a way to give a name declared within file scope internal linkage. This can be done for functions or objects only required within one translation unit. A typical example might be a `help` function printing out the accepted parameters, and which is only called from the `main` function defined in the same `.c` file.

**6.2.2/2** in a C99 draft:

> If the declaration of a ﬁle scope
>   identiﬁer for an object or a function
>   contains  the storage class speciﬁer
>   static, the identiﬁer has internal
>   linkage.

Internal linkage means that the identifier is not visible outside the current translation unit (like the `help` function of above).

#### Volatile

Volatile is a different thing: (**6.7.3/6**)

> An object that has volatile-qualiﬁed
>   type may be modiﬁed in ways unknown to
>   the implementation or have other
>   unknown side effects. Therefore any
>   expression referring to such an object
>   shall be evaluated strictly according
>   to the rules of the abstract machine,
>   as described in 5.1.2.3. Furthermore,
>   at every sequence point the value last
>   stored in the object shall agree with
>   that prescribed by the abstract
>   machine, except as modiﬁed by the
>   unknown factors mentioned
>   previously.

The Standard provides an excellent example for an example where `volatile` would be redundant (**5.1.2.3/8**):

> An implementation might deﬁne a
>   one-to-one correspondence between
>   abstract and actual semantics: at
>   every sequence point, the values of
>   the actual objects would agree with
>   those speciﬁed by the abstract
>   semantics. The keyword `volatile`
>   would then be redundant.

Sequence points are points where the effect of side effects concerning the *abstract machine* are completed (i.e external conditions like memory cell values are not included). Between the right and the left of `&&` and `||`, after `;` and returning from a function call are sequence points for example.

The *abstract semantics* is what the compiler can deduce from seeing only the sequence of code within a particular program. Effects of optimizations are irrelevant here. *actual semantics* include the effect of side effects done by writing to objects (for example, changing of memory cells). Qualifying an object as volatile means one always gets the value of an object straight from memory ("as modified by the unknown factors"). The Standard doesn't mention threads anywhere, and if you must rely on the order of changes, or on atomicity of operations, you should use platform dependent ways to ensure that.

For an easy to understand overview, intel has a great article about it [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/).

#### What should i do now?

Keep declaring your file-scope (global) data as volatile. Global data in itself does not mean the variables' value will equal to the value stored in memory. And static does only make your objects local to the current translation unit (the current `.c` files and all other files #include'ed by it).

Answer (score 44):

First let me mention that a static global variable, is the same as a global variable, except that you are limiting the variable to the scope of the file.  I.e. you can't use this global variable in other files via the `extern` keyword.

So you can reduce your question to global variables vs volatile variables.

**Now onto volatile:**

Like `const`, `volatile` is a type modifier.

The `volatile` keyword was created to prevent compiler optimizations that may make code incorrect, specifically when there are asynchronous events.

Objects declared as `volatile` may not be used in certain optimizations.

The system always reads the current true value of a volatile object at the point it is used, even if a previous instruction asked for a value from the same object. Also, the value of the object is written immediately on assignment.  That means there is no caching of a volatile variable into a CPU register.

[Dr. Jobb's has a great article on volatile](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403766).

Here is an example from the Dr. Jobb's article:

```
class Gadget
{
public:
    void Wait()
    {
        while (!flag_)
        {
            Sleep(1000); // sleeps for 1000 milliseconds
        }
    }
    void Wakeup()
    {
        flag_ = true;
    }
    ...
private:
    bool flag_;
};
```

If the compiler sees that `Sleep()` is an external call, it will assume that `Sleep()` cannot possibly change the variable flag_'s value.  So the compiler may store the value of `flag_` in a register.  And in that case, it will never change.  But if another thread calls wakeup, the first thread is still reading from the CPU's register. `Wait()` will never wake-up.

So why not just never cache variables into registers and avoid the problem completely? 
It turns out that this optimization can really save you a lot of time overall.  So C/C++ allows you to explicitly disable it via the `volatile` keyword.

The fact above that `flag_` was a member variable, and not a global variable (nor static global) does not matter. The explanation after the example gives the correct reasoning even if you're dealing with global variables (and static global variables).

A common misconception is that declaring a variable `volatile` is sufficient to ensure thread safety. Operations on the variable are still not atomic, even though they are not "cached" in registers

**volatile with pointers:**

Volatile with pointers, works like const with pointers.

A variable of type `volatile int *` means that the variable that the pointer points to is volatile.

A variable of type `int * volatile` means that the pointer itself is volatile.

Comment: Nice answer. Only thing I'd add (because it's a common misconception) is that declaring a variable volatile is not sufficient to ensure thread safety. Operations on the variable are still not atomic, even though they are not "cached" in registers

Answer (score 14):

The "volatile" keyword suggests the compiler not to do certain optimizations on code involving that variable; if you just use a global variable, nothing prevents the compiler to wrongly optimize your code.

Example:

```
#define MYPORT 0xDEADB33F

volatile char *portptr = (char*)MYPORT;
*portptr = 'A';
*portptr = 'B';
```

Without "volatile", the first write may be optimized out.

Answer (score 4):

The volatile keyword tells the compiler to make sure that variable will never be cached. All accesses to it must be made in a consistent way as to have a consistent value between all threads. If the value of the variable is to be changed by another thread while you have a loop checking for change, you want the variable to be volatile as there is no guarantee that a regular variable value won't be cached at some point and the loop will just assume it stays the same.

[Volatile variable on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable)

Comment: Cached is not the right word here, the compiler has no control over how the CPU cache handles things.  What you're thinking of is keep the value in a egister rather than reading it from memory.  That's correct, but I wouldn't call it caching.  Thats confusing.

Comment: Wait wait, see my comment on Darron's anser: Volatile is NOT for multithreading!

Answer (score 3):

They may not be in different in your current environment, but subtle changes could affect the behavior.

- Different hardware (more processors, different memory architecture)
- A new version of the compiler with better optimization.
- Random variation in timing between threads.  A problem may only occur one time in 10 million.
- Different compiler optimization settings.

It is much safer in the long run to use proper multithreading constructs from the beginning, even if things seem to work for now without them.

Of course, if your program is not multi-threaded then it doesn't matter.

Comment: 'volatile' in C has nothing to do with multihreading. It just prevents compiler from optimizing it out (eg register mapped to some IO stuff). But it DOES NOT insert memory fences like volatile in Java.

Answer (score 3):

I +1 friol's answer. I would like to add some precisions as there seem to be a lot of confusions in different answers: C's volatile is not Java's volatile.

So first, compilers can do a lot of optimizations on based on the data flow of your program, volatile in C prevents that, it makes sure you really load/store to the location every time (instead of using registers of wiping it out e.g.). It is useful when you have a memory mapped IO port, as friol's pointed out.

Volatile in C has NOTHING to do with hardware caches or multithreading. It does not insert memory fences, and you have absolutely no garanty on the order of operations if two threads do accesses to it. Java's volatile keyword does exactly that though: inserting memory fences where needed.

Answer (score -4):

volatile variable means that the value assinged to it is not constant, i.e if a function containing a volatile variable "a=10" and the function is adding 1 in each call of that function then it will always return updated value.
`{
volatile int a=10;
a++;
}`
when the above function is called again and again then the variable a will not be re-initialised to 10, it will always show the updated value till the program runs.
1st output= 10
then        11
then        12
and so on.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is really wrong. You mixed up `static` and `volatile`.