# Reusing Memory in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management

Just wondering is this kind of code recommended to increase performance?

```
void functionCalledLotsofTimes() {
   static int *localarray = NULL;

   //size is a large constant > 10 000
   if (localarray == NULL) localarray = new int[size];  

   //Algorithm goes here
}
```

I'm also curious how static variables are implemented by modern c++ compilers like g++.  Are they handled like global variables?

Comment: If you make it a parameter, I'd say it's a perfectly valid optimization.

Comment: If `size` is constant, there's little reason to use `new[]` here, either declare it on the stack, or pass it into the function as others have suggested.

Comment: @Justicle: Sometimes stack-space can be an issue. That said, I should have mentioned `std::vector` is more appropriate than a raw pointer.

Comment: @GMan: Performance-wise, using a local static, global or as parameter, all are equal? But the 3rd one needs stack push while the other two are already (always) available, aren't they?

Comment: @Justicle Size is a "constant" that isn't known until runtime

Comment: @legends2k the idea of passing the buffer on the stack is pass its address as a pointer, rather than the whole buffer.

Comment: FYI the classic C idiom for this would be `void functionCalledLotsofTimes( int* bufferToUse, size_t bufferSize)`

Comment: If you have a reasonable upper bound on size, just use that and put localarray on the stack.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not recommended because you are introducing global state to a function.  When you have global state in a function you have side effects.  Side effects cause problems especially in multi threaded programs.

See [Referential Transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)) for more information.  With the same input you always want to have the same output, no matter how many threads you use.

If you want to enable more efficiency, allow the user to specify the buffer themselves as one of the parameters.

See the difference between [global and static variables here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346306/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-global-and-static-volatile-variable).

Answer (score 0):

There is great increase in performance, but you must be very careful how the data will be used. If a multi-thread you must provide access control to data.
do this test :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void StartTime ( LARGE_INTEGER * pTime )
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter ( pTime );
}

ULONG EndTime( LARGE_INTEGER * pTime )
{
    LARGE_INTEGER liDiff;
    LARGE_INTEGER liFreq;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liDiff);

    liDiff.QuadPart -= pTime->QuadPart;
    liDiff.QuadPart *= 1000; // Adjust to milliseconds, shouldn't overflow...

    (void)QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liFreq);

    return ((ULONG)(liDiff.QuadPart / liFreq.QuadPart));
}

void functionCalledLotsofTimesStatic(int size)
{
   static int *localarray = NULL;

   //size is a large constant > 10 000
   if (localarray == NULL) localarray = new int[size];  

   //Algorithm goes here

}

void functionCalledLotsofTimesDynamic(int size)
{
   int *localarray = NULL;

   //size is a large constant > 10 000
   if (localarray == NULL) localarray = new int[size];  

   //Algorithm goes here

   delete [] localarray;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LARGE_INTEGER liTimeDynamic, liTimeStatic;

    StartTime ( & liTimeDynamic );
    for (int loop = 0; loop < 100000 ; loop++ )
    {
        functionCalledLotsofTimesDynamic ( 10000 );
    }
    printf ( "Time dynamic alocation : %lu milliseconds\n", EndTime(&liTimeDynamic));

    StartTime ( & liTimeStatic );
    for (int loop = 0; loop < 100000 ; loop++ )
    {
        functionCalledLotsofTimesStatic ( 10000 );
    }
    printf ( "Time staic alocation : %lu milliseconds\n", EndTime(&liTimeStatic));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the test to see if the static variable has already been initialized is done by "the system" anyway. No need to do it yourself. Just write

```
static int *localarray = new int[size];
```

Only the first time the function is called, the array will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that kind of code is hidden behind a custom allocator class that has a large pre-allocated buffer, so that "dynamic allocations" actually aren't.

Many implementations of std::vector have a more basic form of implementation of this: by default it allocates "blocks" of memory in powers of two, so that no real new allocations need to be done until after the vector has grown to twice the size.