# Can anybody give me example of using Volatile

Tags: java, static, volatile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a static global and static volatile variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346306/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-global-and-static-volatile-variable)

```
public class Test {
volatile  boolean running = true;

public void count() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int counter = 0;
            while (running) {

                counter++;
                System.out.println("Thread 1 counting " + counter);
            }
            System.out.println("Thread 1 finished. Counted up to "
                    + counter);
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {             
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
            System.out.println("Thread 2 finishing");
            running = false;
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Test().count();
}
}
```

I did not found difference between static variable and volatile variable?

In above code I can achieve same thing with static variable also, can any body give me example where only volatile only  fulfills the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

First one that came to my head:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.java.html

Uses volatile on the value to enforce atomicity of updates.